# Question about May's Algebraic Topology book

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I am referring Google Books for the question: [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=g8SG03R1bpgC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=he+group+of+automorphisms+of+a+transitive+G-set&source=bl&ots=tdVLH5CIyK&sig=10Tks2-xqgkLd_XUXXXEJ4Yqvzs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qL0dU_7ZKaL1iQf47IHICQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=he%20group%20of%20automorphisms%20of%20a%20transitive%20G-set&f=false)

in the proof of the first lemma, why is $hns=\phi(hs)$ true? I simply cannot get it...

Comment: Your question really should include enough information that one can answer it without following the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi$ is an automorphism of the $G$-set $S$, i.e. $\phi: S \to S$ is a bijection with $\phi(gt) = g\phi(t)$ for all $g \in G$, $t \in S$. For our particular choice of $s$ in the lemma we know $\phi(s) = ns$, so $\phi(hs) = h\phi(s) = hns$ (since $h \in H \subset G$).

Comment: thanks. I think I haven't encountered this definition of automorphism of G-set, I thought it was just a bijection... where can I find this definition?

Comment: well, Wikipedia, for an easy-to-find example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Morphisms_and_isomorphisms_between_G-sets